# Does org-mode use some markup language?

Tags: org-mode

Does org-mode use some markup language? What is the language called? 
I found that it is similar but different from Markdown. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it uses org-mode syntax. The syntax is documented in the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Markup.html) and in more technical detail [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/dev/org-syntax.html).

Comment: Is the orgmode markup language more or less powerful than Markdown?

Comment: For formatting, they're about the same. But markdown doesn't have an equivalent to org-mode's tags, keywords or properties and it doesn't source blocks.

Comment: I'd say it's hard to compare them, (partly because there are several different flavors of markdown) but org probably has more features. The drawback is that markdown is fairly ubiquitous, while org is emacs-specific. Your friend using Vim or Sublime will not appreciate being sent and org-mode file, while just about everyone has decent tools for working with markdown.

Comment: @Tim Luckily, `org-mode` can [export to Markdown](http://orgmode.org/manual/Markdown-export.html)! :)

Comment: @itsjeyd sure, and even if it didn't you could convert from org to markdown using pandoc. That doesn't really help much if you are writing something collaboratively.